# Maven & proxy settings

Tags: maven, gitlab, to-be-continuous

I'm using the Maven template from To Be Continuous in order to build and deploy into Gitlab Packages.
My corporate network requires proxy to access Maven registry (Maven central) but my runner has direct access to Gitlab.

I set the proxy preferences via http_proxy (and related) var env.
The TBC template values the JVM system properties.
The `mvn package` succeed, but `mvn deploy` fails.

I add the proxy settings inside `settings.xml`.
The `mvn package` succeed, but `mvn deploy` fails.
My understanding: one plugin detects the proxy but ignores the exclusions.

I add a step to unset the var env just before mvn command, keeping the JVM system properties set by TBC template.
The both commands succeed.

What's wrong?

Edit: related to an issue: https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/maven/-/issues/31

Comment: what is the mvn deploy error message?

Comment: I think I found the issue: https://gitlab.com/to-be-continuous/maven/-/issues/31